# Emberjs Power select dynamic options and selectors

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm struggling a bit with the proper pattern to use here. I have a model which represents a power selector called `selector`, each `selector` has a `hasMany` with `selectorOption` which makes up the options for the `selector`

I then have a `dashboardItem` model which loops over each `selector` and implements it.

**route.js**

```
export default Route.extend({

  model(params) {
    return RSVP.hash({
      dashboard: get(this, 'store').findRecord('dashboard', params.dashboard_id),
      selectors: get(this, 'store').findAll('selector'),
    });
  },

  setupController(controller, models) {
    controller.setProperties(models);
  },
});
```

**template.hbs**

```
{{#each selectors as |selector|}}
  <div class="column is-12 object-item">
    <div class="card">
      <header class="card-header">
        <p class="card-header-title">
          {{selector.title}}
        </p>
      </header>
      <div class="card-content">
        {{#power-select-multiple
          placeholder="Vision"
          options=selector.selectorOptions
          searchEnabled=false
          onchange=(action 'something...') as |option|}}
          {{option.title}}
        {{/power-select-multiple}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

I'm not sure what to do on the `onchange`, either with a custom function or using built in tools of power-select.

Each selector is a multi-selector.

This works correctly to the point that I can create any number of selectors and they display on the front end with their correct options as expected.

How should I go about saving the options the users choose against the `dashboardItem`?

Here is a section from the database which shows the models and their relationships. Note there is currently no relationship between a `selector` and a `dashboardItem` (Maybe there should be though?)

```
{
  "selectorOptions" : {
    "-Kyc7on207d_IxnNw2iO" : {
      "title" : "Apple",
      "vision" : "-Kyc7nG9Bz3aEGLked8x"
    },
    "-Kyc7qC9_uxFgXP9c7hT" : {
      "title" : "Orange",
      "vision" : "-Kyc7nG9Bz3aEGLked8x"
    },
    "-Kyc7qqZPMikoG1r3r5g" : {
      "title" : "Bannana",
      "vision" : "-Kyc7nG9Bz3aEGLked8x"
    },
    "-Kyc7uZu8MTfUdH70cBR" : {
      "title" : "Blue",
      "vision" : "-Kyc7rtTPTMJxAPacg-L"
    },
    "-Kyc7vJC3ImzVOEraALx" : {
      "title" : "Green",
      "vision" : "-Kyc7rtTPTMJxAPacg-L"
    },
    "-Kyc7wCrqDz8CD_I-dYy" : {
      "title" : "Red",
      "vision" : "-Kyc7rtTPTMJxAPacg-L"
    }
  },
  "selectors" : {
    "-Kyc7nG9Bz3aEGLked8x" : {
      "title" : "Fruits",
      "selectorOptions" : {
        "-Kyc7on207d_IxnNw2iO" : true,
        "-Kyc7qC9_uxFgXP9c7hT" : true,
        "-Kyc7qqZPMikoG1r3r5g" : true
      }
    },
    "-Kyc7rtTPTMJxAPacg-L" : {
      "title" : "Colours ",
      "selectorOptions" : {
        "-Kyc7uZu8MTfUdH70cBR" : true,
        "-Kyc7vJC3ImzVOEraALx" : true,
        "-Kyc7wCrqDz8CD_I-dYy" : true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to not fight against relationships with basic array storage.

For example

**Base**

```
export default Model.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
  visionOptions: hasMany('vision-option'),
});
```

**Bases Options**

```
export default Model.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
  vision: belongsTo('vision'),
});
```

**The model to save the selected objects on**

```
export default Model.extend({
  //...
  visionOptions: hasMany('vision-option', {async: true}),
  //...
});
```

**The component to handle saving, and selecting the correct objects**

```
export default Component.extend({

  tagName: "",
  classNames: "",

  selectedVisions: computed('dashboardItem.visionOptions', function () {
    const visionId = this.get('vision.id');
    const options = this.get('dashboardItem.visionOptions');

    return options.filterBy('vision.id', visionId);
  }),

  actions: {
    addVision(newList) {
      let dashboardItem = get(this, 'dashboardItem');
      let options = get(this, 'selectedVisions');

      options.forEach(function (me) {
        if (!newList.includes(me)) {
          dashboardItem.get('visionOptions').removeObject(me);
        }
      });

      newList.forEach(function (me) {
        if (!options.includes(me)) {
          dashboardItem.get('visionOptions').pushObject(me);
        }
      });

      dashboardItem.save().then(() => {
        dashboardItem.notifyPropertyChange('visionOptions')
      });
    }
  }

});
```

**Template to render power-select**

```
  {{#power-select-multiple
    placeholder=""
    options=vision.visionOptions
    searchEnabled=false
    selected=selectedVisions
    onchange=(action 'addVision') as |vision|}}
    {{vision.title}}
  {{/power-select-multiple}}
```

This allows there to be an unknown number of "visions", with an unknown number of "visionObjects" to be loaded and saved.

The `notifyPropertyChange` is required to update the computed property so the frontend renders when a user adds or removes a selected object. This is only awkward because there isn't a direct known database key.